# Reverse-engineering a clustering algorithm from the clusters

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, feature-selection

I have a clustering of data performed by a human based solely on their knowledge of the system. I also have a feature vector for each element. I have no knowledge about the meaning of the features, nor do I know what the reasoning behind the human clustering was.

I have complete information about which elements belong to which cluster. I can assume that the human was not stupid and there is a way to derive the clustering from the features.

Is there an intelligent way to reverse-engineer the clustering? That is, how can I select the features and the clustering algorithm that will yield the same clustering most of the time (on this data set)?

So far I have tried the naive approach - going through the clustering algorithms provided by the sklearn library in python and comparing the obtained clusters to the source one. This approach does not yield good results.

My next approach would be to use some linear combinations of the features, or subsets of features. Here, again, my question is if there is a more intelligent way to do this than to go through as many combinations as possible.

I can't shake the feeling that this is a standard problem and I'm just missing the right term to find the solution on Google.

Comment: I voted to move this question to http://stats.stackexchange.com/, they accept questions on data mining and machine learning. Some control questions: was this "manual" clustering algorithm performed on a single dataset, or maybe you have several datasets clustered using the same principles? Do you know anything about the principles behind that manual clustering (maybe human assumed a fixed number of clusters before seeing data, maybe human assumed some points in the dataset do not belong to any cluster, maybe human used visual representation of data during clustering)?

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure where to post it. It was originally a scikit question that got more general as I wrote it. There is only one data set. I know the principles behind the clustering but how it translates to the features. A good example would be: Taken a group of objects, a human clustered (or given the reply below I guess they classified) them based on what material they appear to be made of ("probably metallic"). Now my feature set would be the molecules found in the objects, their densities, elasticity, etc - unlabelled. It's possible that there are some unrelated features, like eg shape.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it was done *automatically*?

It sounds to me as if you should be treating this as a *classification* problem: construct a classifier that does the same as the human did.

Comment: Thanks, I was so stuck on clustering I had neglected to think of other options. I'll take a look at classification methods.